# My GUI does not load

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have created a GUI for a text based game I am trying to make.
I implemented the GUI into the already working game mechanics, but when I load it, the GUI does not appear. 
There are no errors on the page, and eclipse will run the rest of the game, just not anything related to the GUI.
(I have added the entire code for the GUI, but only included a part of the game to shorten the code.)
The code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                DemoGUI inst = new DemoGUI();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public DemoGUI() {
        super();
        initGUI();
    }
    public void initGUI() {
        try {
            FlowLayout thisLayout = new FlowLayout();
            getContentPane().setLayout(thisLayout);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                jLabel1 = new JTextArea();
                getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
                jLabel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 250));
                jLabel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

                jButton1 = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(jButton1);
                jButton1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
                jButton1.setText("Map");
                jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    }
                });

                jButton2 = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(jButton2);
                jButton2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
                jButton2.setText("Inventory");
                jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jText1.setText("Health: " + EAID.CharHealth);
                        jText1.setText("Number of potions: " + EAID.CharPotionLevel);
                        jText1.setText("Weapon: ");
                        jText1.setText("Armor: ");
                    }
                });

                jButton4 = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(jButton4);
                jButton4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
                jButton4.setText("Return");
                jButton4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jLabel1.setText("");
                        jText1.setText("");
                    }
                });

                jText1 = new JTextField();
                getContentPane().add(jText1);
                jText1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 100));
                jText1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

                jButton3 = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(jButton3);
                jButton3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
                jButton3.setText("Submit");
                jButton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jText1.setText("");
                        jLabel1.setText("THIS IS A TEST");
                    }
                });


                //Scanner   
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            //Introduction  
                jLabel1.setText("Hello adventurer. This is a tale of old, taking place in the long lost kingdom of Asteroth.\r\n" + 
                    "This is a land tormented by the tyranical rule of the Lich King Astotle.\r\n" + 
                    "For centuries he has tormented the citizens, leading to widespread famine and terror throughout the land.\r\n" + 
                    "The story you are about to go on follows the tale of a young hero, on there quest to bring peace to the land.\r\n" + 
                    "But tell me adventurer..");
```

This is added to the very bottom of the document before the class and main strings are closed:

```
pack();
            this.setSize(350, 500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Start with something simple. Just create a JFrame and show the frame. Then add a single label to the frame. Do one step at a time instead of trying the write the entire application before you start testing. Then when the code stops working you know the last change you made and can fix it or ask a specific question on why it doesn't work. My guess is the Scanner is causing the problem. It is blocking waiting for input.

Comment: I had created the GUI in a separate project. It had loaded properly in there, yet when I tried to add it to the rest of my game, is when it failed to load, the Try block was used in a tutorial I was following (This is for a class project)

Comment: Removing the scanner allowed the GUI to load

Comment: Instead of using the scanner to read from the Console - blocking i/o - use a text area to read user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Removing the scanner allowed the GUI to load

So you can't execute the Scanner on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

So you need to create another `Thread` for the `Scanner`. One way to do this is to use a `SwingWorkder`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the `EDT` and an example that uses a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Camickr: please note [his last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010424/using-the-jtextfield-as-an-input-for-a-game?noredirect=1). Looks like a help vampire, one who asks before even looking at the tutorials.

Comment: And he re-asked a similar question, one very much related to this one, without acknowledging your contribution. Not good.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks, another vampire to be aware of.